# Flutter chat_ui bad text encoding

Tags: flutter, character-encoding

I'm using the package [flutter_chat_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_ui), when sending a word that contains accents, I get a text with special characters.

[image]

I looked on the package documentation but I couldn't find how to change the encoding.

**My code** : I get a list of messages from the server and then display them in the chat.

```dart
class MyChatPageState extends State<MyChatPage> {

  List<types.Message> _messages = [];
  final _user = const types.User(id: '82091008');

  // Get messages from the server
  startGetChatMessages() async{
    chatMessages().then((value){
      List result = json.decode(value.body);
      setState(() => _messages = result; );
    }).catchError((onError){
        ...
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startGetChatMessages(); // Get messages
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Chat(
      messages: _messages,
      onSendPressed: _handleSendPressed,
      user: widget.userMe,
      onPreviewDataFetched: _handlePreviewDataFetched,
    );
  }


  // When the user presses the send button
  void _handleSendPressed(types.PartialText message) {
    final textMessage = types.TextMessage(
      author: widget.userMe,
      createdAt: DateTime
          .now()
          .millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      id: randomString(),
      text: message.text,
    );

    _addMessage(textMessage); // send message
  }

}
```

Comment: share your code, special where you define a get methode

Comment: Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.  You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Tété'.encode('utf-8') .decode( 'latin1')` returns `TÃ©tÃ©`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several searches I understood that the error came from the encoding of the message retrieved on the server: I should therefore decode the messages in utf8 as indicated by the code below:

#### I used this:

```dart
List result = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(value.bodyBytes));
```

#### Instead of this:

```dart
List result = json.decode(value.body);
```

And it works.